# Handling a custom exception without changing the test class (java)

Tags: java, exception

I need to throw a couple times a custom exception. A test class is checking if my solution works but I'm not allowed to make any changes to this class which leads me to my problem.
I simplified the problem here, because the whole code is not needed here

```
public class Test{
    public static final String s = "0test";
    
    @Test
    public void testZero(){
        Solver sol = new Solver(Parser.run(s));   
        //IntelliJ is underlining "run" because "Unhandled exception: ParseException", a 
        //simple solution could be adding "throws ParseException" in the head, but I'm not
        //allowed to change the test class
    }
}
public class Parser{
    public static Pars run(String input) throws ParseException{
        if(input.charAt(0) == '0'){
            throw new ParseException("...");
        }
    } 
}
public class ParseException extends Exception{
     public ParseException(String mess){ 
         super(mess);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problem.
In my ParseException class, I need to change it  to:

```
public class ParseException extends IllegalArgumentException{...}
```

Further into the task, the test class didnt accept my exception because there was a IllegalArgumentException exspected.
Changing it into "extends IllegalArgumentException" solves the problem, so I dont need "throws ParseException" in the headings and no try,catch statements

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not allowed to make any changes to this class which leads me to my problem.

There is no way that you can throw an Exception to the `Test` class without catching it over there.

BUT you can prematurely just catch it inside the `Parser#run(String input)`.

Instead of this:

```java
public static Pars run(String input) throws ParseException{
    if(input.charAt(0) == '0'){
        throw new ParseException("...");
    }
}
```

You could (as I said) catch it in the method instead.

```java
public static Pars run(String input) {
    try {
        if(input.charAt(0) == '0'){
            throw new ParseException("...");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // System.out.println(e.toString());
        // Just handle it over here if you can't edit Test.java ...
    }
}
```